# Error when using knots for a twist

Tags: tikz-knots

The code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby, knots}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=90,scale=3]% remove 'scale=3' to get the error
    \begin{knot}[flip crossing=1,consider self intersections=true,
      ignore endpoint intersections=false]
      \strand (0,1) to[out=-90,in=90](0,0.5) to [out=270, in=270]
        (0.3,0.5)to [out=90, in=90]
        (0,0.5)to[out=-90,in=90] (0,0);
    \end{knot}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

uses the `knots` package to produce:

[image]

(It's rotated only to take up less space.) This is what I want, except that it is too large. Unfortunately, removing the `scale=3` from the `tikzpicture` environment gives the error:

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>  \LaTeX3 error:
> Erroneous variable \knotnextfilament6 used!
> l.14         \end{knot}x

Does anyone have any idea why this error occurs and how to fix it to get a smaller twist? (Of course, I could just rescale the image using `\scalebox` but this hack does not really solve the problem.)

In some sense the error is caused by the `ignore endpoint intersections=false` because without this the code compiles producing:

[image]

This does not solve my problem, however, as the crossing has been replaced by in intersection

The post [Crossings in tikz knots package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/570111/crossings-in-tikz-knots-package/570377#570377) shows several ways to draw the twist using the `knots` package, so I can draw the diagram that I want, however, I still do not understand why the code above does not work when `scale=3` is removed.

Comment: Not an answer but a workaround: moving the control points slightly away from each other and using an edge for the stretch that is in the foreground anyway avoids the error: `\strand (0,1) to[out=-90,in=90](0,0.55) to [out=-90, in=-90]
        (0.3,0.5)to [out=90, in=90]
        (0,0.45)edge(0,0);`

Comment: Thanks! Perhaps this is the answer: I just need to use slightly different points. This might explain why the error goes away if I remove the `ignore endpoint intersections=false`.

Comment: The source of the problem is that the crossing is *exactly* where one segment ends and another begins.  I suspect it is miscounting the number of crossings, I'll investigate to see what's going on.  In the meantime, there are various possible solutions.  How exact is your picture?  Must the path follow exactly what you have specified, or can it vary slightly?

Comment: @AndrewStacey Thanks Andrew. The picture can vary slightly -- I'm just drawing Reidemeister moves as, as mentioned above, your post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/570111/crossings-in-tikz-knots-package/570377#570377 gives ways of doing this. Btw, I'm growing to love your knots and spytj3 packages as I get more used to using them.

Comment: Always pleased to hear about someone using these packages!  Have you seen the newer way of drawing knots using the spath3 tikz library?  Back to your example, the problem does seem to be with the crossing being at the end of a segment.  Changing the coordinates to `(0,0.501)` and `(0,0.499)` in that order fixes the problem.  Interestingly, if I put `(0,0.5001)` and `(0,0.4999)` then it still compiles but it thinks that there are three crossings at that point.  (This is using pdflatex, other engines might have different precision boundaries).

Comment: Okay, there *is* a bug in the package which I have now tracked down and squished.  The update is on github.  _However_, with both coordinates at `(0,0.5)` then it finds 4 crossings so I still recommend adjusting them slightly to ensure that it only finds 1.

Comment: @AndrewStacey `Have you seen the newer way of drawing knots using the spath3 tikz library?`: Hmm, perhaps I'm too impatient. I started drawing the diagrams that I needed  by dipping in the manuals and following code I found on the net. Sometimes I used  `knots`, sometimes `hobby` and  sometimes with `spath3`. I never worked out the relationships between the three packages and, in particular,  whether the latter ones superceded or complemented the earlier ones. Perhaps I missed this in the documentation?

Comment: I'm not sure I have a clear picture and I wrote all three of those!  The main two are `knots` and `spath3`; the `hobby` package is for designing the curves in the first place and the others are for rendering the intersections as knots.  They work in different ways, `knots` overdraws while `spath3` cuts.  I'd say that neither is superior, but sometimes one is more appropriate than the other. If you want to illustrate 3-colouring, for example, then `spath3` is better. If your paths are decorated, often the overdrawing method is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me sum up the comments into an "answer".

There were really two issues with the code.  The first is that there was a bug in the package, which is now squished in the version on [`github`](https://github.com/loopspace/spath3).

The second is that the crossing point is actually where several segments of the strand start or end.  This leads to it being found more times than is warranted.  In short, when `consider self intersections` is set then the path is split up into segments (which themselves might be further split as bézier curves can self-intersect) to find the self-intersection points.  In this case, even without the further split then the crossing point is found four times: between segments 1 and 3, 1 and 4, 2 and 3, 2 and 4 (the package does recognise that the intersection between, say, segments 1 and 2 is spurious).

The simplest fix for this is to adjust the end points of the segments so that the crossing does not occur at such an end point.  Experimenting shows that adjusting them to `(0,0.501)` and `(0,0.499)` is sufficient.

The reason why the `scale` affects things is because by the time the knots library gets to work then all coordinates have been converted into dimensions so the tolerances and tests are all in terms of `pt`.